# Hide errors in ASP:ValidationSummary

Tags: asp.net, error-handling, validationsummary

Is there a way to hide the individual errors in a ASP:ValidationSummary so that only the HeaderText is displayed?

I'm using the ASP:RegularExpressionValidator to return the individual errors inline so I don't need them returned in the summary.

Comment: You can override the Javascript that generates the summary:
`var ValidationSummaryOnSubmitOrig = ValidationSummaryOnSubmit;
var ValidationSummaryOnSubmit = function() {
  // Call the original code or do whatever you want.
  // ValidationSummaryOnSubmitOrig();
}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically, the Text property of a validator is displayed inline and the ErrorMessage property value is displayed in the ValidationSummary. Try not setting the ErrorMessage property or set it to an empty string and see if that creates the effect you are aiming for.

Comment: Thanks.  I found that setting the ErrorMessage to and empty string and setting the Text to the message I want displayed inline did the trick.